# Aligning images in Markdown

Tags: image, alignment, markdown

It is my understanding that markdown image alignment defaults to left, but mine is rendering center. I would like it to align left. I'm using Visual Studio Code for the editor and hugo server to check local changes. This is the code.

```
![Alt text.](/images/spring-cutback/MarkingBulbs.png?width=25pc)
```

I've already tried different HTML and CSS variations for alignment, none of which has worked.

[Image is centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoSl5.png)

[Code from developers tools.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5VTI.png)

Comment: you say this is the code, but there isn't one?

Comment: Sorry. I just edited the question and the code is in there now.

Comment: Can you share a link that we can visit to discover why images are appearing centered? Without knowing why, we can't tell you how to fix it.

Comment: This is an internal document so I can't link it, but I've taken screen shots of the page and the code and added it to the question.